# How to read from Flame Sensor in C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, sensors, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I have sensor like this: https://easyelectronyx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/flame.jpg?i=1

Please can anyone help me ? I need to find code to read from it , in C#. I have Raspberry Pi 2 Model B , Windows 10 IoT Core and programming in C#. I cant find documentation on the Internet. Is it needed to wire Analog output ? 

Thanks

Comment: What's your sensor device? From the picture you attached I can't get any useful information.

Comment: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Comment: I asked for **sensor** not Raspberry Pi.

Comment: https://easyelectronyx.com/product/flame-sensor-module-for-arduinorpi/

Answer (score 2):

This Frame sensor device can provide digital or analog output based on its [datasheet](http://www.fut-electronics.com/wp-content/plugins/fe_downloads/Uploads/Flame-sensor-arduino.pdf).

If you don't like to use analog output you can get output from digital pin ***DO***.

First, connect the Frame sensor and Raspberry Pi. Connect VCC, GND and DO like the following picture show. For digital pin, I choose GPIO27 here, you can choose other pin you like.

[image]

Second, write the code. Create the UWP app([Start here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworld)).

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Name="SensorOuputValue" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private const int SENSOR_PIN = 27;
    private GpioPin pin;
    private GpioPinValue pinValue;
    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        timer.Tick += ReadSensor;
        InitGPIO();
        if (pin != null)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void InitGPIO()
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        // Show an error if there is no GPIO controller
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            pin = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There is no GPIO controller on this device.");
            return;
        }

        pin = gpio.OpenPin(SENSOR_PIN);
        pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GPIO pin initialized correctly.");

    }

    private void ReadSensor(object sender, object e)
    {
        SensorOuputValue.Text = pin.Read().ToString();
    }

}
```